# Notification icon is not displaying

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving a notification but without notification icon...
I don't understand why the icon is not displaying in the notification

```
notification:
            {

                title: `Hey ${userName}`,
                body: `You Have One New Notification`,
                icon: "default",
                color: "#0000FF",
                sound: "default",
                priority: "high",   


            }
```

**Firebasemessagingservice**

```
 String notificationTitle=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
 String notificationbody=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

 String click_action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
 // String from_user_id=remoteMessage.getData().get("User_data");

 NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.uemround)
                .setContentText(notificationbody)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

 Intent resultIntent=new Intent(click_action);
 //resultIntent.putExtra("user_id",from_user_id);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent= (PendingIntent) PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
 mbuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

 int mnotificationId=(int)System.currentTimeMillis();
 NotificationManager mnotifymgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 mnotifymgr.notify(mnotificationId,mbuilder.build());
```

Comment: do you see any system default notification icon

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add notification channel for the version oreo and above. Copy the below code and run it. It will work

 // NotificationChannels are required for Notifications on O (API 26) and above.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    String channelId = "Channel_id";
                    CharSequence channelName = "Your app name";
                    int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);
                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                    if (notificationManager != null) {
                        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) // channel id is mandatory
                                .setContentTitle(title)
                                .setContentText(body)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setVibrate(pattern)
                                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1, 1)
                                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    // and icon should be transparent for lollipop and above version
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
        } else { 
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        } 
                        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
                    }
                } else {
                    if (notificationManager != null) {
                        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "")//no need to add the channel id
                                .setContentTitle(title)
                                .setContentText(body)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setVibrate(pattern)
                                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1, 1)
                                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
// and icon should be transparent for lollipop and above version
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
        } else { 
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        } 
                        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

onMessageRecieved ->

check -> if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) then
you can set your data as per your requirement and then

```
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notification_channel_id)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("Title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("Body"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

//                    .setContentInfo("Important")
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                    .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setNumber(++numMessages)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

sorry for bad english ;-)